# Generating state snapshot (syncing)

Tags: go-ethereum, snapshot

I am trying to do a fast sync on geth, its been running for 2 days. eth.syncing returns false, however I am two days behind on on blocknumbers. Geth is only "Generating state snapshot" the accounts and slots are increasing. Does this mean that I am still syncing?

Comment: did you upgrade to 1.10.6 to support the features of Fork released on 5 August (EIP 1559) ?

Comment: syncing = `false` means you already have the lastest block and it is most likely number  12,964,999

Comment: Correct, 12964999 is my latest block but on etherscan the lates block is 12984360?

Comment: yep, well with your old `Geth` you can only sync to block 12,964,999

Comment: My old geth do I need to upgrade it?